# suppress DataError Event in DatagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I got a DataGridView in a C# windows Form, which fills data from an excel file.

I bind the excel to grid like this

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + filePath + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
            OleDbConnection oledbconnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

                oledbconnection.Open();
                OleDbCommand oledbcommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [StudentInformationSheet$]", oledbconnection);
                oledbadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oledbcommand);
                ds = new DataSet();
                oledbadapter.Fill(ds, "Passengers");
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        GridViewPassenger.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                    oledbconnection.Close();
```

---

**Requirement**

After filling the grid i can edit grid.. I want some fields as not mandatory.Lets say 3 fields, DOB,Age, Address are not mandatory. so i can clear the data in the cell.

---

**Problem**

when i clear the address field its worked fine. now i clear the DOB cell and click the next cell there come a message box like this
[image]

and same with Age column with message "string was not recognize as a valid Int32"

---

How can i get rid of the checking....

is there any way to suppress this?

**EDIT 1**

I found a similar question here

[DataError Dialog Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504807/dataerror-dialog-box)

But did't help me much.

**EDIT 2**

I put this event

```
private void GridViewPassenger_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
```

Now the message box gone...But i cant commit the empty cell.. When I clear the cell and then i cant click anywhere else in the form. the only chance is to click <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then the edit id gone...it restores to the value in cell.

Is there any way to change the datatype of column to string of the datagridview?

---

**Solved**

Myself found a solution. i will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Before binding the dt to grid I change the datatype of dt column.

Here is my additional code.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + filePath + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
            OleDbConnection oledbconnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

                oledbconnection.Open();
                OleDbCommand oledbcommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [StudentInformationSheet$]", oledbconnection);
                oledbadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oledbcommand);
                ds = new DataSet();
                oledbadapter.Fill(ds, "Passengers");
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

                DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();

                dtCloned.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(string);
                dtCloned.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(string);

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
                }
                GridViewPassenger.DataSource = dtCloned.DefaultView;
                oledbconnection.Close();
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of suppressing the error you can handle the error in cell_leave event:

```
Private Sub DGV_RowEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV.RowEnter
        Dim theDate As DateTime
        If Date.TryParse(DGV(0, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString, theDate) Then
            DTP.CustomFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
            DTP.Value = theDate
        Else
            DTP.CustomFormat = " "
        End If
    End Sub
```

The above code is further explained in the answer in the following link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4cdf1a3e-ed84-41ae-9e22-a8108a371dff/null-value-from-datagridview-to-datetimepicker?forum=Vsexpressvb

Comment: can u give the code in c#. I cant convert the VB code correctly to c#